# C++ Overloaded function, one takes takes argument of base class, another takes argument of derived class

Tags: c++

Sorry if this is a duplicate question but couldn't find any relevant results myself.

I have class A, and derived class B which is derived from A.

I have the following overloaded function:

```
void print(A* obj) {
    printf("This is an A object.");
}
void print(B* obj) {
    printf(This is a B object.");
}
```

And I do the following in my main.

```
B* bObj = new B;
print(bObj);
```

What exactly are the rules by which is chosen to call? Does the order in which the overloaded functions are declared matter?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly are the rules by which is chosen to call?

The overload resolution rules. They are described in the section [over.match] of the standard. The section is about 20 pages long, so concise description may be helpful: The candidate whose arguments require unambiguously the least conversions is preferred.

> Does the order in which the overloaded functions are declared matter?

Yes, but only in relation to the function call. Only the overloads that have been already declared are considered:

```
void print(A*);

void foo() {
    B* ptr = nullptr;
    print(ptr); // will call void print(A*)
}

void print(B*);
```

Otherwise, the order of declaration is not significant.

Comment: Thank you, that was a very good description! I did come across overload resolution but it was so long I didn't know if it had anything to do with my question so I skipped it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The order doesn't matter. The rules are such that the *most specific* overload must be taken - in this case the B version.

Please also note that the function call is inserted at compile time - that is, it doesn't depend on the actual runtime type and therefore does not insert a virtual/dynamic lookup. So should you change to

```
A* bObj = new B;
print(bObj);
```

Then a call to the function take `A*` will be called.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied.